# java does not parse for 'M dd, yyyy' date format

Tags: java, date-format

I want to parse date strings like `"February 7, 2011"` using `"M dd, yyyy"` format. But I get an exception.

Comment: The number of `M` matters. `MM` is the month as a number and `MMM` is the month as a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your parsing string is not correct as mentioned by others
- To correctly parse `February` you need to use an english Locale or it may fail if your default Locale is not in English

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date dt = df.parse("February 7, 2011");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.  I ran it with two dates "November 20, 2012" and "January 4, 1957"  and got this output:

```
arg: November 20, 2012 date: Tue Nov 20 00:00:00 EST 2012
arg: January 4, 1957 date: Fri Jan 04 00:00:00 EST 1957
```

It works fine.  Your regex was wrong.

```
package cruft;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * DateValidator
 * @author Michael
 * @since 12/24/10
 */
public class DateValidator {
    private static final DateFormat DEFAULT_FORMATTER;

    static {
        DEFAULT_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        DEFAULT_FORMATTER.setLenient(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String dateString : args) {
            try {
                System.out.println("arg: " + dateString + " date: " + convertDateString(dateString));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println("could not parse " + dateString);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Date convertDateString(String dateString) throws ParseException {
        return DEFAULT_FORMATTER.parse(dateString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it does, I just ran it.  Where do you think I got the output that I posted for you?  If you give dates on the command line, be sure to surround them in quotes.  The command line parser looks for spaces.

Comment: @duffymo To parse a month in English, you need to use an English locale. My guess is that the default Locale of the OP is not English.

Comment: Good point.  I think I did enough for the OP to take that up if they need to.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use "MMM dd, yyyy"

```
SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").parse("February 7, 2011")
```

See [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `SimpleDateFormat`, the month format is incorrect, it should be `MMM dd, yyyy`

`MMM` will match the long text format of the month:

```
String str = "February 7, 2011";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(str);
```